# Use list comprehensions to make a list of count of elements smaller than the element in an array

Tags: python, list

I was solving this leetcode problem - https://leetcode.com/problems/how-many-numbers-are-smaller-than-the-current-number/

I solved it easily by using nested for loops but list comprehensions have always intrigued me. Ive spent a lot of time to make that one liner work but I always get some syntax error.

here's the solution:

```
count = 0
ans = []
for i in nums:
    for j in nums:
        if i > j:
            count = count + 1
    ans.append(count)
    count = 0
return ans
```

these were the ones so far I think shouldve worked:

```
return [count = count + 1 for i in nums for j in nums if i > j]
return [count for i in nums for j in nums if i > j count = count + 1]
return [count:= count + 1 for i in nums for j in nums if i > j]
```

Ill also be happy if there's some resource or similar to put it together, Ive been searching the python docs but didnt find something that'll help me

Comment: I don't understand what you think `range` means or why you expect to be able to use it like that.

Comment: But instead of trying to increment a count inside the comprehension - comprehensions are fundamentally not about re-assigning values; they're about *processing a sequence* - try to come up with a comprehension to get *the actual elements* of `j` that are smaller than the current element of `i`, and *then* check how many there are, using `len`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtelKal that's my bad typing it out here, made the edits sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, three people write `sum` solutions but every single one does `sum(1 for ...)`. I prefer this:

```
[sum(j < i for j in nums) for i in nums]
```

Answer (score 3):

I will transform the code step by step in order to show the thought process.

First: we don't care what the value of `count` is *afterward*, but we need it to be `0` at the *start of each inner loop*. So it is simpler logically to set it *there*, rather than outside and then also at the end of the inner loop:

```
ans = []
for i in nums:
    count = 0
    for j in nums:
        if i > j:
            count = count + 1
    ans.append(count)
return ans
```

Next, we focus on the contents of the loop:

```
    count = 0
    for j in nums:
        if i > j:
            count = count + 1
    ans.append(count)
```

A list comprehension is not good at math; it is good at producing a sequence of values from a source sequence. The transformation we need to do here is to put *the actual elements* into our "counter" variable<sup>1</sup>, and then figure out how many there are (in order to append to `ans`). Thus:

```
    smaller = []
    for j in nums:
        if i > j:
            smaller.append(j)
    ans.append(len(smaller))
```

Now that the *creation* of `smaller` has the right form, we can replace it with a list comprehension, [in a mechanical, rule-based way](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/). It becomes:

```
    smaller = [j for j in nums if i > j]
    #          ^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^
    #          | \- the rest of the parts are in the same order
    #          \- this moves from last to first
    # and then we use it the same as before
    ans.append(len(smaller))
```

We notice that we can just fold that into one line; and because we are passing a *single* comprehension argument to `len` we can drop the brackets<sup>2</sup>:

```
    ans.append(len(j for j in nums if i > j))
```

Good. Now, let's put that back in the original context:

```
ans = []
for i in nums:
    ans.append(len(j for j in nums if i > j))
return ans
```

We notice that the same technique applies: we have the desired form already. So we repeat the procedure:

```
ans = [len(j for j in nums if i > j) for i in nums]
return ans
```

And of course:

```
return [len(j for j in nums if i > j) for i in nums]
```

---

1. Another popular trick is to put a `1` in the output for each original element, and then `sum` them. It's about the same either way; last I checked the performance is about the same and I don't think either is clearer than the other.
2. Technically, this produces a *generator expression* instead. Normally, these would be surrounded with `()` instead of `[]`, but a special syntax rule lets you drop the extra pair of `()` when calling a function with a *single* argument that is a generator expression. This is especially convenient for the built-in functions `len` and `sum` - as well as for `any`, `all`, `max`, `min` and (if you don't need a custom sort order) `sorted`.

Comment: Small feedback: In this question we're looking for integers that are `less than` another integer. However, all the comparisons that are used here are `greater than`. It doesn't change anything in the code, however if the intent is to look for smaller objects, I think that object should come first.

Comment: Agreed. There's also a question as to what is supposed to happen when the values are equal. From the way OP describes the problem, it sounds like there is a logical error there, which I have faithfully reproduced. :)

Comment: In the question at leetcode they say: `That is, for each nums[i] you have to count the number of valid j's such that j != i and nums[j] < nums[i].` So I think you've answered the question correctly.

Comment: @HampusLarsson I want LeetCode to show me a case where `j == i` and `nums[j] < nums[i]` :-)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel None of your `len(generator expression)` solutions work.

Answer (score 1):

Using `counter` inside the list comprehension creates the challenge of resetting it's value, each iteration of the first loop.

This can be avoided by filtering, and summing, in the second loop:

1. You use the first loop to iterate over the values of `nums` array.

```
return [SECOND_LOOP for i in nums]
```

2. You use the second loop, iterating over all elements of `nums` array. You filter in the elements that are smaller than `i`, the current element in the first loop, with `if i < j`, and evaluating `1` for each of them. Finally, you sum all the `1`s generated:

`sum(1 for j in nums if i > j)`

You get the number of values that meet the requirements, by the list comprehension of the first loop:

```
return [sum(1 for j in nums if i > j) for i in nums]
```

This solution has been checked & validated in LeetCode.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to advance an external counter, try adding ones to your list and then sum it:

for example:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5]
target = 3

print(sum(1 for n in nums if n < target))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a slightly different approach for the inner loop than a list comprehension. Instead of repeatedly *appending* a value to a list you need to repeatedly *add* a value to a variable.

This can be done in a functional way by using `sum` and a *generator expression*:

> ```
> count = 0
> # ...
> for j in nums:
>     if i > j:
>         count = count + 1
> ```

can be replaced by

```
count = sum(1 for j in nums if i > j)
```

So that we now have this:

```
ans = []
for i in nums:
    count = sum(1 for j in nums if i > j)
    ans.append(count)
return ans
```

This pattern can in fact be replaced by a list comprehension:

```
return [sum(1 for j in nums if i > j) for i in nums]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternative Solution

We can also use the Counter from collections:

```
class Solution:
    def smallerNumbersThanCurrent(self, nums):
        count_map = collections.Counter(nums)
        smallers = []
        for index in range(len(nums)):
            count = 0
            for key, value in count_map.items():
                if key < nums[index]:
                    count += value
            smallers.append(count)
        return smallers
```